# Hide Back text in navigation item

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uinavigationitem

I need to set a back arrow by replacing back Text(button)in navigation bar. I can view the back arrow but i don't know how to hide the back Text in navigation item.  Here's is my code:

with this am getting warning : : CGImageCreateWithImageProvider: invalid image size: 0 x 0.

```
(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
 {
    UIImage *backButtonHomeImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"back-arrow.png"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 104, 13)];
    [[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackButtonBackgroundImage:backButtonHomeImage  forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = nil;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
UIImage *backButtonHomeImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"back-arrow.png"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 104, 13)];
```

Answer (score 3):

The answer

```
    -(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
     {
        [super viewWillAppear:animated];
        if([self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0] != self)
        {
            UIButton *backButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 26, 26)];
            [backButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"back-arrow.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [backButton setShowsTouchWhenHighlighted:TRUE];
            [backButton addTarget:self action:@selector(popViewControllerWithAnimation) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
            UIBarButtonItem *barBackItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:backButton];
            self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = TRUE;
            self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = barBackItem;
        }
}

-(void)popViewControllerWithAnimation
{  
   [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];

}
```

may it will help.

Comment: works perfect for me but what if I want to do the same for right bar button.

Answer (score 0):

Just set blank text to title of navigation bar before pushing to that view Controller as below code.

```
self.navigationItem.title=@" ";
```

Comment: Smartwork: It's working now, but the arrow show's in middle. Need to show in corner?

Comment: Smartwork: If i extended the space it shows dot's. i framed UIImage *backButtonHomeImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"back-arrow.png"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 104, 13)];

Answer (score 0):

Create custom back button and add that button to Navigation controller's back button.

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom]; 
button.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,54,32);
UIImage *backButtonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"back-arrow.png"];
[button setBackgroundImage:backButtonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button addTarget:self.navigationController action:@selector(popViewControllerAnimated:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

UIBarButtonItem *barButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:button];
[self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:barButtonItem];
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this would work

```
 self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:nil action:nil] autorelease];
```